# Send message through Facebook API from personal account to a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

Is their a way to send a private message on Facebook from your personal account to a Facebook page, from an external app ? (through the API or else)

Exactly as if you were contacting a page manually, by I wanna be able schedule the messages to send to the page, and let a software send it for you.

I've seen so many topics in SO but no one giving a answer to this specific situation.

Thanks

Comment: removed the fql tag, because fql is deprecated/gone since many years

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible.

You can not automate sending user messages at all.